# pyspark error: pandas_udf expression not supported

Tags: pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

Code is using a struct below to define a pyspark dataframe (version 2.4.7)

```
schema = T.StructType([T.StructField('key', T.StringType(), True),
                    T.StructField('date', T.StringType(), True),
                    T.StructField('values1', T.FloatType(), True),
                    T.StructField('values2', T.FloatType(), True),
                    T.StructField('values3', T.FloatType(), True),
                    ])
```

A window function is as defined below

```
schema = T.StructType([T.StructField("v", T.DoubleType())])
@F.pandas_udf(schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
def exponential_average(v):
    alpha = 0.5
    fit = v.ewm(alpha=alpha).mean()
    return fit
```

When applying a window function pyspark throws an error: `Expression 'exponential_average(values3#508)' not supported within a window function.`

```
window = Window.partitionBy(F.col('key'))\
                    .orderBy('date')\
                    .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing)
df.withColumn('test', exponential_average(F.col('values3')).over(window))
```

is there something wrong with using `F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP`?

Comment: did you mean to use `GROUPED_AGG`?

Comment: @mck can you elaborate why `GROUPED_AGG` would make sense here. The function `exponential_average` returns a series and not a aggregated scalar, correct?

Comment: You're using it in a window, so you're aggregating the rows in the window into a single scalar value, if I understood correctly

Comment: @mck sorry about the confusion, the rows in the window are being aggregated to a vector of values (same size as the window).

Comment: then you can return an array of doubles?